# Go module where package name is different to github path

Tags: go

I want to add a go package to my `go.mod` file. But it's called e.g. `https://github.com/user/something` but the actual package in the source files is e.g. `somethingelse`. How can I add this to my go.mod file? Just doing this doesn't work:

```
import somethingelse github.com/user/something
```

I get an error:

```
module declares its path as: somethingelse
        but was required as: github.com/user/something
```

Comment: I tried that but how would I use it in this case? What do I put as the target?

Comment: OK thanks, that's going to be a pain for CI. I think I'll just fork the repo and rename it.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following to your `go.mod` file:

```
replace somethingelse => github.com/user/something latest
```

then, import as:

```golang
import "somethingelse"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a Go package to your go mod file first download your package to your local repo using

`go get github.com/user/something`

Then import the package to your program it will get imported, well if you are using Visual studio code then your package will be auto imported when you write code with the syntax of that specific package and save the program.

If that doesn't import automatically, then import it manually or just run a command on your IDE terminal which is

`go mod tidy`

This command will basically match the `go.mod` file with the dependencies required in the source files.

- Download all the dependencies that are required in your source files
  and update `go.mod` file with that dependency.
- Remove all dependencies from the `go.mod` file which are not required
  in the source files.

Comment: Is there no way of doing this directly in a go.mod file? I don't want to introduce extra steps to my build process, only `go build`

Comment: How does this answer the question? This is not enough to handle the package naming mismatch.