# Issue when running go mod tidy declares X but was required Y

Tags: go, import, package

I'm having an issue with setting up a go module. I'm really a go noob and I have tried tons of solutions to similar problems from similar stack overflow articles but I really can't seem to figure this out.

When I import as follows in my main.go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/Grapphy/shcaptcha"
)
```

I get the following issue when running `go mod tidy`

```
go: finding module for package github.com/Grapphy/shcaptcha
go: found github.com/Grapphy/shcaptcha in github.com/Grapphy/shcaptcha v0.0.0-20220207203634-9183bfa83c3f
go: example.com/test imports
    github.com/Grapphy/shcaptcha: github.com/Grapphy/shcaptcha@v0.0.0-20220207203634-9183bfa83c3f: parsing go.mod:
    module declares its path as: shcaptcha
            but was required as: github.com/Grapphy/shcaptcha
```

It seems there is some issue I can't resolve downloading the module I want. It seems very confusing to me. Would really appreciate it if someone can kindly explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I might resolve this issue. Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your reply, but now I am super confused. That's how they import it on the github example https://github.com/Grapphy/shcaptcha

Comment: same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69691443/8535534